# Unexpected token in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, post, vue.js, mongoose, backend

I'm getting this error on a POST method, but im pretty sure im doing it right..

Error:

```
Unexpected token f in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse
```

This makes sense sort of...well 'token f' makes sense, thats what my data starts with: field1: "##########"

heres my api's post function:

```
var putNewNums = (data) => {
    fetch('/getnums', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then(res => res.send())
}
```

which goes to this route:

```
app.use('/getnums', getRouter)
```

which goes to this controller:

```
router.post('/', mainController.postNums)
```

which looks like this:

```
postNums: (req, res, next) => {
    numSchem.create({
        field1: req.body.field1
    })
    .then(data => res.status(200).json(data))
    .catch(e => {
        req.error = e
        console.log(e)
        next()
    })
}
```

not exactly sure where my error is..im sending it a string just like my schema wants:

```
const nums = mongoose.Schema ({
    field1: String,
})
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

here is the error i am now getting after changing req.boy to req.body.field1 in my postNums function:

```
{ ValidationError: numSchema validation failed: field1: Cast to String failed for value "{ field1: '8773238968' }" at path "field1"
at ValidationError.inspect (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:59:24)
at formatValue (util.js:400:38)
at inspect (util.js:294:10)
at format (util.js:161:12)
at Console.log (console.js:130:21)
at numSchem.create.then.catch.e (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/controllers/main.js:47:12)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  errors: 
   { field1: 
      { CastError: Cast to String failed for value "{ field1: '8773238968' }" at path "field1"
    at new CastError (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:29:11)
at model.$set (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:879:7)
at model._handleIndex (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:688:14)
at model.$set (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:645:22)
at model.Document (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:112:12)
at model.Model (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:69:12)
at new model (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4344:13)
at toExecute.push.callback (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2479:22)
at /Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/async/internal/parallel.js:31:39
at eachOfArrayLike (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/async/eachOf.js:65:9)
at exports.default (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/async/eachOf.js:9:5)
at _parallel (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/async/internal/parallel.js:30:5)
at parallelLimit (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/async/parallel.js:88:26)
at utils.promiseOrCallback.cb (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2489:5)
at Promise (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:243:5)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    message: 'Cast to String failed for value "{ field1: \'8773238968\' }" at path "field1"',
    name: 'CastError',
    stringValue: '"{ field1: \'8773238968\' }"',
    kind: 'String',
    value: [Object],
    path: 'field1',
    reason: [Object] } },
  _message: 'numSchema validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

Comment: _"thats what my data starts with: field1: "##########""_ - then the response is invalid JSON

Comment: Where in this series of operations is the parse error coming from? Are you using a body parser? What is `data`?

Comment: @charlietfl I cant really tell from the error itself, though im getting a new error now, I changed: numSchem.create({
        field1: req.body
    })
to field1: req.body.field1 and get a cast to string failed for value which looks like its coming from my schema but i'm not 100% about that..

Comment: '{ "field1": 8773238968 }' is a valid JSON string......  "{ field1: 8773238968 }" is not. Still missing the bit of code with the parse in it

Comment: @uzer

Huh..

I was able to post these numbers earlier with literaly the same exact code as what i have upthere.. so im not sure how to go about fixing this now.

Comment: Whats the value of req.body.field1? I'm pretty stuck too

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) and found that the value of this is: "field1" : "field1" : "phone number here"

It had two field ones.

I fixed it by saying: JSON.stringify(data.field1) rather than JSON.stringify(data) though i think it can be fixed multiple ways.